# Obj-C CocoaPods + Swift Framework

Tags: swift, afnetworking, cocoapods, xcode6

I'm creating a Swift framework in the latest Xcode 6 DP4. I need to internally use AFNetworking in my framework, but can't figure out a way to compile it.

I know how to use bridging headers, but those aren't supported in Swift frameworks.

---

My framework, Core.framework, looks like this:

```
> Core.h
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>

    //! Project version number for Core.
    FOUNDATION_EXPORT double CoreVersionNumber;

    //! Project version string for Core.
    FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char CoreVersionString[]; 

> SomeFileThatNeedsAFNetworking.swift
```

And I'm using a podfile to bring in AFNetworking. However, when I compile, I get the following error:

```
<unknown>:0: error: ~/Core/Source/Core.h:2: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'Core'
```

because of the AFNetworking import. But if I don't include that, then I get compilation errors everywhere referencing AFNetworking.

Has anyone figured out the right combination?

Comment: Have you tried changing the build setting CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES or 'Allow Non-module includes In Framework Modules' to Yes? Just search 'module' in the Frameworks Build Settings to find it

Comment: I'm having the same issue with FMDB. Allowing non-modular headers doesn't work either.

Comment: Same issue here with another pod.

Comment: Same with another pod. So it seems that it's not possible to use an objc cocoapod inside a swift custom framework right?

Comment: Same issue here trying to integrate SSZipArchive in Swift Framework..

Answer (score 3):

Well, based on what I'm seeing [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2218) and [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/2222) I don't think it is possible to compile anything from a pod file just yet. I have tried to do this with the SCLAlertView-Swift library with similar errors. I think you will just have to wait for the code to get developed by the cocoapods team.

Answer (score 1):

So I have something working. My goal was to use a shared code framework across multiple targets with cocoapod libraries for support in sharedCode. Problems I had were the non-modular header issue and the duplicate symbols issue.

MainTarget
-swift files

SharedCode
-swift files
-objc files
-cocoapods lib

Add a 'Run Script Phase' to the top of the 'framework' target

```
set -e

RESOURCES_TO_COPY=${PODS_ROOT}/headers-to-copy-${TARGETNAME}.txt
> "$RESOURCES_TO_COPY"

ls -d -1 ${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/**/*.h >> "$RESOURCES_TO_COPY"

rsync -avr --copy-links --no-relative --exclude '*/.svn/*' --files-from="$RESOURCES_TO_COPY" / "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/Headers"

rm -f "$RESOURCES_TO_COPY"
```

In the framework main header put

```
#import <{SHARED_FRAMEWORK_NAME}/PixateFreestyle.h>
#import <{SHARED_FRAMEWORK_NAME}/Lockbox.h>
#import <{SHARED_FRAMEWORK_NAME}/etc.h>
```

Voila, the classes are now available to your framework code and to your framework dependencies if needed. This does expose all of the cocoapods headers and the copy script is not smart so you may run into a path issue. So far so good for me though. This is certainly a work-around since the non-modular header thing blocks the compiler.